# Trouble fetching pdf (React, Node, Express)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, pdf

I'm rebuilding a site for a client, and the site requires that when you click on a button a pdf is served to the front-end from the server. I've made my own dummy server with the same endpoints to replicate how the server functions, but I'm struggling to get the pdf. 
This is the first time I've ever really worked with PDFs in a web development context, hence the ignorance. Please trust that I've done **a lot** of Googling.

Some issues I have are:

1. some sources say that to send a pdf with Node and Express you simply
   use res.downoad('path/to/filename') but I haven't managed to get it
   working that way.
2. Because I'm using React Router if I try to call the pdf route with an anchor tag I get redirected to that route (if I do e.preventDefault()) nothing happens.
3. Other sources use an AJAX call to pull in the pdf, and I can do this but I don't know how to process it in the then block.

   4. [Another source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545044/download-pdf-file-from-api) said I just needed to use window.open(url) on the front end, but that also just follows the React router route and doens't do anything.

The wording of the url for the pdf route is "/historical_report/daily_risk_report_2019_02_18.pdf/fundname" 
And I can see that that url is retrieving a pdf from the client's server.

My questions are:

1. What is the correct way to get a pdf like this in React? Should I just use an anchor tag? Or do I actively need to use Fetch/Axios?
2. Is res.download sufficient for serving the pdf from the server?

I've tried using this on the front-end:

```
fetch(
      url,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/pdf",
          "Content-Type": "application/pdf"
        }
      }
    )
      .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
          return response
      })
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(response => {
        var blob = response;
        var reader = new window.FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onloadend = function() {
          var base64data = reader.result;

          window.open(base64data);
        };
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

and this on the backend:

```
router.get('my url', (req, res) => {
    res.download('url')
})
```

but no luck (this is returning a 404 error... ) It would be great if someone could offer some advice. Thanks in advance.